Como utilizar ou simular o space-evenly numa lista ul para dividir a lista em 2 colunas e posicioná-las?
Utilizei uma ul com 2 span para separar dois grupos de li para que eu pudesse utilizar o space-evenly na ul e posicioná-los. Porém a não utilização direta de li após ul gera um problema de acessibilidade. Por isso queria resolver isso somente com uma ul e li.
layout desejado: layout desejado da ul
HTML:
<ul>
                <span>
                    <li>1.5 - <abbr title="Bolo de Copo">Cupcake</abbr></li>
                    <li>1.6 - <abbr title="Rosquinha">Donut</abbr></li>
                    <li>2.1 - <abbr title="Bomba">Eclair</abbr></li>
                    <li>2.2 - <abbr title="Iogurte Congelado">Froyo</abbr></li>
                    <li>2.3 - <abbr title="Biscoito de Gengibre">Gingerbread</abbr></li>
                    <li>3.0 - <abbr title="Favo de Mel">Honeycomb</abbr></li>
                    <li>4.0 - <abbr title="Sanduíche de Sorvete">Ice Cream Sandwich</abbr></li>
                </span>

                <span>
                    <li>4.1 - <abbr title="Jujuba">Jelly Bean</abbr></li>
                    <li>4.4 - <abbr title="KitKat">KitKat</abbr></li>
                    <li>5.0 - <abbr title="Pirulito">Lolipop</abbr></li>
                    <li>6.0 - <abbr title="Marshmallow">Marshmallow</abbr></li>
                    <li>7.0 - <abbr title="Torronne">Nougat</abbr></li>
                    <li>8.0 - <abbr title="Oreo">Oreo</abbr></li>
                    <li>9.0 - <abbr title="Torta">Pie</abbr></li>
                </span>
            </ul>

CSS:
main > article > aside > ul {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-evenly;
list-style: inside "\2714\00A0\00A0";

}
@media (min-width: 435px) {
main > article > aside > ul {
flex-direction: row;
}
}

Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Você consegue esse comportamento com o css:
ul {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

O grid-template-columns vai dividir o conteudo em N partes, definido dentro do repeat.
Referência da propriedade: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns
